# Day light saving in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a requirement where I want to send the current date with time as '00:00:00' from a scheduler. Since the scheduler run in UTC, I am converting it like below

**Code Tried:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun format(d: DateTime) = (d as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"} >> 'PST')
---
{
    "fromDate" : (format((now() as Date as String ++ "T07:00:00Z") as DateTime)),
    "toDate" : format((now() as Date as String ++ "T07:00:00Z") as DateTime),

}
```

The above code works fine but during day light saving, it is giving me out as

**Current Output:**

```
{
  "fromDate": "2021-11-09T23:00:00-08:00",
  "toDate": "2021-11-09T23:00:00-08:00"
}
```

As you can see it is giving me previous day 11pm date instead of current date 00:00:00.

How can we handle both before and during the daylight saving dynamically in dataweave and get the expected out  in both cases

**Expected Output:**

```
{
  "fromDate": "2021-11-10T00:00:00-08:00",
  "toDate": "2021-11-10T00:00:00-08:00"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mule 4.4 you can use the new function atBeginningOfDay():

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Dates
---
{
    simpler: (now() ++ |07:00:00|) >> "PST",
    beginning: atBeginningOfDay(now() >> "PST")
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "simpler": "2021-11-09T23:00:00-08:00",
  "beginning": "2021-11-10T00:00:00-08:00"
}
```

Note that you are doing many not need type conversions when you are calculating the date time. Doing that will reduce performance. Just format after all time calculations. I added an example ('simpler'). In this case the default formatting will do.

For Mule 4.3 or earlier this is an alternate method that should work for PST:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun alternatePstBeginningOfDay()=do {
    var t=now() as Date 
    var tz="PST" as TimeZone
    var offset=t ++ tz
    ---
     (t ++ |00:00:00|) as DateTime >> "PST"  
          +("PT$(abs(offset.offsetSeconds))S" as Period)
}
---
{
    alternate: alternatePstBeginningOfDay() 
}
```